# how to default select values of multiselect primeng with displaying labels

Tags: angular, primeng

how to select by default values of multiselect primeng, need this for form update

code:

```
@Component({
  template: `<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" ></p-multiSelect>`
})
export class MyComponent {

  cities: SelectItem[];
  selectedCities= [];


  public constructor() {
        this.cities = [];
    this.cities.push({ label: 'Paris', value:{id:'1',country:'France', name:'paris'}  });
    this.cities.push({ label: 'Madrid', value:{id:'2',country:'Spain', name:'madrid'}  });
    this.selectedCities.push({id:'2',country:'Spain', name:'madrid'})
  }
```

current behavior: the values are salected in the list but label got a null

Answer (score 0):

Yo've to add `optionLabel="name"` to your p-multiSelect element:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" optionLabel="name"></p-multiSelect>
```